# Show residual grade in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to do something pretty basic but can't seem to get my head around it. - I'm no Excel expert.

Basically I'm trying to work out how far away from a target grade a student is.

For example:

Student X, Target Grade B, Actual Grade C = 
Student X's residual grade would would be -1

I have a list of students and their target/actual grades, how could I work this out in Excel using a formulae?

> Student X, C, A = +2
>
> > Student Y, D, A = +3

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your data set up as follows

A1: Name
B1: Grade
C1: Goal

use the following formula in D1

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,{"A",0;"B",1;"C",2;"D",3;"F",4},2,0)-VLOOKUP(C1,{"A",0;"B",1;"C",2;"D",3;"F",4},2,0)
```

From there you can drag the formula down

Answer (score 0):

Formula assumes you have your Target letter grade in Column B and your Actual Letter grade in column C.  Also assumes you are using a letter grade system of "A, B, C, D, F" only.

Formula will return "Seriously?" any time the value of the target grade is set to a lower grade than the Actual grade

```
=IF(CODE(C2)< CODE(B2),"Seriously?",IF(C2="f",CODE(B2)-CODE(C2)+1,CODE(B2)-CODE(C2)))
```

Adjustment was made if the actual grade is "F" since the formula is using the ASCII Code numbers based on the letter provided and F is two letters away from D but only one letter grade away from D.